# Pass key-value list via JAX-RS param

Tags: java, jax-rs

I have defined GET method as described below:

```
@GET
@Produces("text/plain")
@Path("method/{id}/{value}")
public void method(@PathParam("ids") final String id, @PathParam("value") final String value) {}
```

It allows me to pass one `id` and `value`. How can I pass a bunch of pairs `id/value` to this method ?

Comment: Does it need to be a GET? A looks like a POST or PUT would be more appropriate, is it storing a list of id=value?

Comment: It works right now as a `GET`, however I can convert it to `POST`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one way to do it is to create your-own-protocol, something like this:

> method/1,2,3,4,5,6,7/one,two,three,four,five,six,seven

and then, in your code parse the "protocol":

```
public void method(@PathParam("ids") final String idStr, @PathParam("value") final String valueStr) {
    String[] ids = idStr.split(",");
    String[] values = valueStr.split(",");
}
```

but it pretty ugly

the second one is to use POST body, in that case you can't use GET, and you should create a ValuesMapObject, that holds a map between each id to it value and send it from the client, in that case the function will be look like this:

```
@POST
@Produces("text/plain")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Path("method/ids_and_values")
public void method(ValuesMapObject values) {}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use `HashMap<Long,String>` instead of `ValuesMapObject` ?

Comment: It's a bit tricky, try to look http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.2.GA/userguide/html_single/index.html#JAXB_Map . It might be possible but I always prefer to create a wrapper class.